# Fluid Layout - how to get initial percentage value

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

When creating a fluid layout as a base for a responsive design - how do you reach the inital percentage value for the main container.  For example a fixed layout might start with the container of 930px wide with a 15px padding on either side.

I need to know how to get that inital 930 value expressed as a percentage.

Comment: Do you mean like this: `930/(930+15*2) = 930/960 = 0.97`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The container will be a percentage relative to the body. Check out http://robot-or-not.com/ and you'll notice the container div `#page` is set to 85%.